# Problema al generar el sello para CFDi 3.3

Tags: c#, sha1

Buenas tardes, 
estoy en el proceso de cambio de cfdi 3.2 a 3.3.

Una vez generada la cadena original, leyendo en otros posts encontré una validador de la misma y está correcta, a la hora de generar el sello con SHA 256, me muestra un error.

> "Excepción no controlada del tipo
>   'System.Cryptography.CryptographicException' Información Adicional:
>   'Algoritmo especificado no es válido'"

Puesto que pude verificar que la cadena original está correcta copio la parte donde intento generar el sello.

```
string co = generarCadenaOriginal(oCFDi);
X509Certificate2 _MiCertificado = new X509Certificate2(@"" + rutaP12, @"" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PublicKey"], X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA1 = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)_MiCertificado.PrivateKey;


UTF8Encoding eUTF = new UTF8Encoding(true);
byte[] tester = eUTF.GetBytes(co);
SHA256CryptoServiceProvider hasher = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();

byte[] signedBytes = RSA1.SignData(tester, hasher);

return Convert.ToBase64String(signedBytes);
```

Agradezco me puedan ayudar, 
Saludos para todos

Comment: En qué línea de código te marca el error?, en la del haser?

Comment: Yo tuve un problema similar al pasar los certificados digitales a 256 bits (no recuerdo exactamente), opté por usar la clase de BouncyCastle: https://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/index.html

Comment: Me marca el error en la penúltima línea, cuando intento crear el sello. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenos días, les comparto mi experiencia con este cambio al intentar firmar con la llave privada del certificado y generar el sello en el CFDI v3.3 con digestión SHA256 con RSA.

Se tiene que especificar **explícitamente** el Proveedor de Servicios Crytograficos de Microsoft a la hora de integrar nuestras claves privadas con nuestros certificados indicando que vamos a usar "Microsoft Enhanced RSA y AES Cryptographic Provider" como nuestro CSP.

De la siguiente manera desde OpenSSL, en mi caso:

```
pkcs12 -export -in certificado.cer.pem -inkey llave.key.pem -CSP "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" -out certificado.p12
```

Este problema viene del CSP que se tiene en windows, cuando llamamos a SignData con SHA256, la función CryptCreateHash se llamará, este API de cifrado no realiza operaciones de cifrado por sí mismo, redirecciona los parámetros que obtiene de la aplicación al CSP deseado y el CSP realiza las operaciones en su nombre.

Para verificar que se haya generado correctamente:

```
pkcs12 -info -nodes -in certificado.p12
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto puedes ahora desde .NET en mi caso hacer lo siguiente sin problema:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)_MiCertificado.PrivateKey;
SHA256 hasher = SHA256CryptoServiceProvider.Create();
byte[] signedBytes = rsa.SignData(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cadenaOriginal), hasher);
```

Ya con esto se puede generar el sello correctamente y el algoritmo será valido al hacer el firmado.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo utilizar la dll de openssl para ese trabajo, o en su defecto, utilizar directamente el openssl sobre los archivos cer y key.

Ahora bien, enfocandonos sólo a tu código, si ya tienes el firmado para cfdi 3.2, puedes utilizar el mismo código, sólo reemplazando el hasher de SHA1 a SHA256.

En mi experiencia, el mejor mecanismo para realizar el firmado de los certificados es utilizando el exe de openssl.

Comment: Buenos días, gracias por la respuesta. Esto intento mantuve el mismo código, y es que me muestra este error. Saludos

Comment: Excelente, esperaba que me corroboraban esto ya que estoy próximo a actualizar también.